# Run a service when the application is opened and redirect to the corresponding Activity in Android

Tags: android, android-activity, android-service

When the application is launched for the first time. the login page will be visible. Once the user logs in, he will be redirected to the dashboard page. I am saving the user login details. So when the user opens the application again, I want to navigate to dashboard page instead of login.

What is the right procedure to achieve this? I can do this in MainActivity or through a service. Is it possible to do this with Service? Suggestions please..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set a boolean flag to check if the user already logged in or not. set the flag to true and save it with your user's login credential,after successful login, and retrieve the boolean value of the flag when your app start (onCreate of MainActivity). You will not need a separated service.

you should save your user's login credential on a place from where the data will not be removed after the app is closed. If you need then please go to [storage option](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html)

Answer (score 0):

Services are not the best candidate for this scenario. The best way is to save a key-value pair in [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html). So your workflow would be:

- at every launch of app, go and fetch the username and password(you should save salted pass) from the shared pref.
- If its not there, this is your first time launch, redirect to login
  screen.
  Otherwise redirect to your mainActivity.

You don't need a separate activity for handling this, this logic can be put in onCreate() of your mainActivity.